# PHP Export query to Excel

Tags: php, html, excel

I need help to insert rule in Excel.
I Have vary dates and IF that date is already last background is Red. 
Need for row[4]

```
for($i=1; $i<=$aux; $i ++){
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from tables = $id = ".$i) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$html .= '<tr><td>'.$row[0].'</td>
<td>'.$row[1].'</td>

<td>'.$row[2].'</td>

<td>'.$row[3].'</td>

<td>'.$row[4].'</td>
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: put the cell red when the date expires

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a proper Excel worksheet in PHP with formulas and what not, take a look at this Pear package: **Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer**

http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer

Writing forumulas:

```
integer Worksheet::writeFormula(
    integer $row , integer $col , string $formula , mixed $format=0)
```

More info: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.spreadsheet-excel-writer-worksheet.writeformula.php